# How to detach and then use a SQL Server database file in ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem while developing asp.net application with SQL Server database.
when I select a database then I get the message:

> This file is in use. Enter a new name or close the file that's open in
> another program

Then I saw a help which says that first detach the database. But when I detach the database then it vanishes from SQL Server Management Studio then how can I connect with that database? One more thing is that when I try to open database file (which I have detached already) then it says that:

> The attempt to attach to the database failed with the following information.
> Login failed for user 'xyz'.

Comment: Are you using `AttachDbFilename` in the connection string?

Comment: No, i am trying to create a connectionString using GUI provided by asp.net. Using SqlDataSource.

Comment: Do you have the MDF file open elsewhere? Can you post the full connection string (you can obfuscate the server name if necessary)

Comment: You must of done the deattach wrong.  Seen this before.  You need an admin to change the permissions of the MDF file in windows.  When you do a deattach you need to do from a query.  When you use the explorer  to deattach it changes permission of the MDF and then you  need admin to fix issue.